# Error while implementing Parallel_Pipeline in Intel TBB

Tags: c++, tbb

I am doing one implementation of filter with parallel pipeline function in Intel TBB .In the code it give this error

none of the 2 overloads could convert all the argument types in the parallel_pipeline code line. The code which i have used is shown below:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <sstream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <tbb/pipeline.h>
#include <tbb/atomic.h>
#include <tbb/concurrent_queue.h>
#include <tbb/compat/thread>
#include <tbb/tbbmalloc_proxy.h>    
using namespace std;
using namespace tbb;

#define pi 3.141593
#define FILTER_LEN  265

double coeffs[ FILTER_LEN ] =
{
  0.0033473431384214393,0.000032074683390218124,0.0033131082058404943,0.0024777666109278788,
  -0.0008968429179843104,-0.0031973449396977684,-0.003430943381749411,-0.0029796565504781646,
  -0.002770673157048994,-0.0022783059845596586,-0.0008531818129514857,0.001115432556294998,
  0.0026079871108133294,0.003012423848769931,0.002461420635709332,0.0014154004589753215,
  0.00025190669718400967,-0.0007608257014963959,-0.0013703600874774068,-0.0014133823230551277,
  -0.0009759556503342884,-0.00039687498737139273,-0.00007527524701314324,-0.00024181463305012626,
  -0.0008521761947454302,-0.00162618205097997,-0.002170446498273018,-0.002129903305507943,
  -0.001333859049002249,0.00010700092934983156,0.0018039564602637683,0.0032107930896349583,
  0.0038325849735515363,0.003416201274366522,0.002060848732332109,0.00017954815260431595,
  -0.0016358832300944531,-0.0028402136847527387,-0.0031256650498727384,-0.0025374271571154713,
  -0.001438370315670195,-0.00035115295209013755,0.0002606730012030533,0.0001969569787142967,
  -0.00039635535951198597,-0.0010886127490608972,-0.0013530057243606405,-0.0008123200399262436,
  0.0005730271959526784,0.0024419465938120906,0.004133717273258681,0.0049402122577746265,
  0.0043879285604252714,0.002449549610687005,-0.00040283102645093463,-0.003337730734820209,
  -0.0054508346511294775,-0.006093057767824609,-0.005117609782189977,-0.0029293645861970417,
  -0.0003251033117661085,0.0018074390555649442,0.0028351284091668164,0.002623563404428517,
  0.0015692864792199496,0.0004127664681096788,-0.00009249878881824428,0.0004690173244168184,
  0.001964334172374759,0.0037256715492873485,0.004809640399145206,0.004395274594482053,
  0.0021650921193604,-0.0014888595443799124,-0.005534807968511709,-0.008642334104607624,
  -0.009668950651149259,-0.008104732391434574,-0.004299972815463919,0.0006184612821881392,
  0.005136551428636121,0.007907786753766152,0.008241212326068366,0.00634786595941524,
  0.003235610213062744,0.00028882736660937287,-0.001320994685952108,-0.0011237433853145615,
  0.00044213409507615003,0.0022057106517524255,0.00277593527678719,0.0011909915058737617,
  -0.0025807757230413447,-0.007497632882437637,-0.011739520895818884,-0.013377018279057393,
  -0.011166543231844196,-0.005133056165990026,0.0032948631959114935,0.011673660427968408,
  0.017376415708412904,0.018548938130314566,0.014811760899506572,0.007450782505155853,
  -0.001019540069785369,-0.007805775815783898,-0.010898333714715424,-0.00985364043415772,
  -0.005988406030111452,-0.001818560524968024,0.000028552677472614846,-0.0019938756495376363,
  -0.007477684025727061,-0.013989430449615033,-0.017870518868849213,-0.015639422062597726,
  -0.005624959109456065,0.010993528170353541,0.03001263681283932,0.04527492462846608,
  0.050581340787164114,0.041949186532860346,0.019360612460662185,-0.012644336735920483,
  -0.0458782599058412,-0.07073838953156347,-0.0791205623455818,-0.06709535677423759,
  -0.03644544574795176,0.005505370370858695,0.04780486657828151,0.07898800597378192,
  0.0904453420042807,0.07898800597378192,0.04780486657828151,0.005505370370858695,
  -0.03644544574795176,-0.06709535677423759,-0.0791205623455818,-0.07073838953156347,
  -0.0458782599058412,-0.012644336735920483,0.019360612460662185,0.041949186532860346,
  0.050581340787164114,0.04527492462846608,0.03001263681283932,0.010993528170353541,
  -0.005624959109456065,-0.015639422062597726,-0.017870518868849213,-0.013989430449615033,
  -0.007477684025727061,-0.0019938756495376363,0.000028552677472614846,-0.001818560524968024,
  -0.005988406030111452,-0.00985364043415772,-0.010898333714715424,-0.007805775815783898,
  -0.001019540069785369,0.007450782505155853,0.014811760899506572,0.018548938130314566,
  0.017376415708412904,0.011673660427968408,0.0032948631959114935,-0.005133056165990026,
  -0.011166543231844196,-0.013377018279057393,-0.011739520895818884,-0.007497632882437637,
  -0.0025807757230413447,0.0011909915058737617,0.00277593527678719,0.0022057106517524255,
  0.00044213409507615003,-0.0011237433853145615,-0.001320994685952108,0.00028882736660937287,
  0.003235610213062744,0.00634786595941524,0.008241212326068366,0.007907786753766152,
  0.005136551428636121,0.0006184612821881392,-0.004299972815463919,-0.008104732391434574,
  -0.009668950651149259,-0.008642334104607624,-0.005534807968511709,-0.0014888595443799124,
  0.0021650921193604,0.004395274594482053,0.004809640399145206,0.0037256715492873485,
  0.001964334172374759,0.0004690173244168184,-0.00009249878881824428,0.0004127664681096788,
  0.0015692864792199496,0.002623563404428517,0.0028351284091668164,0.0018074390555649442,
  -0.0003251033117661085,-0.0029293645861970417,-0.005117609782189977,-0.006093057767824609,
  -0.0054508346511294775,-0.003337730734820209,-0.00040283102645093463,0.002449549610687005,
  0.0043879285604252714,0.0049402122577746265,0.004133717273258681,0.0024419465938120906,
  0.0005730271959526784,-0.0008123200399262436,-0.0013530057243606405,-0.0010886127490608972,
  -0.00039635535951198597,0.0001969569787142967,0.0002606730012030533,-0.00035115295209013755,
  -0.001438370315670195,-0.0025374271571154713,-0.0031256650498727384,-0.0028402136847527387,
  -0.0016358832300944531,0.00017954815260431595,0.002060848732332109,0.003416201274366522,
  0.0038325849735515363,0.0032107930896349583,0.0018039564602637683,0.00010700092934983156,
  -0.001333859049002249,-0.002129903305507943,-0.002170446498273018,-0.00162618205097997,
  -0.0008521761947454302,-0.00024181463305012626,-0.00007527524701314324,-0.00039687498737139273,
  -0.0009759556503342884,-0.0014133823230551277,-0.0013703600874774068,-0.0007608257014963959,
  0.00025190669718400967,0.0014154004589753215,0.002461420635709332,0.003012423848769931,
  0.0026079871108133294,0.001115432556294998,-0.0008531818129514857,-0.0022783059845596586,
  -0.002770673157048994,-0.0029796565504781646,-0.003430943381749411,-0.0031973449396977684,
  -0.0008968429179843104,0.0024777666109278788,0.0033131082058404943,0.000032074683390218124,
  0.0033473431384214393
};


//! Buffer that holds Sine Wave Data.

class MyBuffer 
{
    public:
    double *acc;
    double *buffer;
    int start,end;

    static int j;

    MyBuffer()
    {
        start=0;
        end=0;

       buffer=new double[150264];
       acc=new double[150000];
       fill_n(buffer,150264,0);
    }

    ~MyBuffer()
    {
        delete[] buffer;
        delete[] acc;
    }
    int startnumber()
    {
        return start;
    }
    int endnumber()
    {
        return end;
    }
};


int MyBuffer::j=0;


typedef concurrent_queue<MyBuffer>  QueueMyBufferType;
QueueMyBufferType chunk_queue;

atomic<bool> stop_flag;



void input_function()                               
{   

    stop_flag = false;    

    while(MyBuffer::j<=150000)    
    {   

        MyBuffer b;                                                     
        b.start=(FILTER_LEN-1+(MyBuffer::j));
        b.end=(25264+(MyBuffer::j));

        for(int i =b.startnumber(); i <b.endnumber(); i++)
         {
                b.buffer[i] = sin(700 * (2 * pi) * (i / 5000.0));

         }

         chunk_queue.push(b);
         MyBuffer::j+=25000;
     }

    stop_flag = true;

}

int main()
{
    int ntokens = 4;            //quad core

    thread input_thread(input_function);

    bool stop_pipeline = false; 


    **parallel_pipeline(ntokens,make_filter<void, MyBuffer*>**
        (            
            filter::parallel,[&](flow_control& fc)-> MyBuffer*
            {               

                if (stop_pipeline)
                {                   
                    fc.stop();      
                    return NULL;// functor g0 should call stop at the end 
                }   

                MyBuffer* b=new MyBuffer;
                //MyBuffer* b=new MyBuffer;

                //MyBuffer* b=new MyBuffer;

                if(!chunk_queue.try_pop(*b))
                {               
                    if (stop_flag) 
                    {
                        stop_pipeline = true;
                    }
                }               
                return b;
            }
        )&  
        make_filter<MyBuffer*, MyBuffer*>
        (       
            filter::parallel,
            [&](MyBuffer* b)-> MyBuffer*
        {                               

                double *coeffp;
                 int n,k,ip,nip;


                for ( n = (b->startnumber()-264); n <(b->endnumber()-264); n++ )
                 {
                coeffp = coeffs;
                ip=(FILTER_LEN - 1 + n);
                nip=0;

                b->acc[n]=0;

                for ( k = 0; k < FILTER_LEN; k++ )
                {
                     nip=ip-k;
                    b->acc[n]+= ((*coeffp++) * (b->buffer[nip]));                 //
                }

                }
               return b;
        }
        )&  

        make_filter<MyBuffer*, MyBuffer*>
        (   
            filter::serial,
            [&](MyBuffer* b)-> MyBuffer*
            {
                ofstream o;

                for (int n1 = (b->startnumber()-264); n1 < (b->endnumber()-264); n1++ )
                 {
                    o<<n1<<","<<b->buffer[n1+FILTER_LEN-1]<<","<<b->acc[n1]<<endl;   
                }

                 delete b; 
            }

        )
    );  

    cout << "\n All Data is processed \n\n" << endl;        
    return 0;
}
```

i have highlighted the line.Please help to find where i am getting wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The last filter shall be `make_filter<MyBuffer*, void>`. See [TBB reference manual](http://threadingbuildingblocks.org/docs/help/reference/algorithms/parallel_pipeline_func.htm) :)